# Add additional permissions to Instagram API Review

Tags: api, permissions, instagram, review

I have been approved for two permissions with the Instagram API.

I now want to apply for approval to use an additional permission/scope. If this additional permission/scope is rejected, will I lose the two ones I currently have? Or are the ones I currently have unaffected by any new ones I apply for?